# how do i make two if statements with seperate conditions execute at the same time

Tags: javascript, html

I'm very new to coding, only learning HTML & CSS about a year ago and just learning javascript about a week ago. I decided to create a cookie clicker-type project in order to try and improve my JS skills and everything works fine except for one thing. These two if statements i have below are not executing together. I want to make them both execute so that if the banana count is equal to 10,000 then it should add a single farm and also change the html elements.

The reason they are two seperate if statements is that I had to add a second condition (!addFarm1) to check if a var is false then make it true so that it only adds the farm once instead of every click after 10,000 banana counts.

How i want it to work is that once banana count reaches 10000, a single farm is added to the farm count and ALSO changes the html elements to match the 'upgrade' then changes the interval. There is much more code but i didnt know if i should post it so i just posted the important parts but please ask if you need the rest of the code to fix it.

```
var addFarm1 = false;

function countByTwo(num1) {
    for (let i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
        bananaCount += 2;
    }
    return bananaCount;
}

function addFarm(farmAdd) {
    farmCount = farmCount + farmAdd;
    farmCountText.textContent = farmCount;
    farmIncrementText.classList.remove('hidden');

    farmIncrement = farmCount * 5;
    farmIncrementText.textContent = '+' + farmIncrement;

    setInterval(function() {
        bananaCount = bananaCount + farmIncrement;
        bananaCountText.textContent = bananaCount;
    }, 1000);
}

function bananaClick() {
    bananaCount += 1;

    if (bananaCount > 10000) { // this one to change the clicker image, text, and interval
        bananaClicked.textContent = 'Golden Banana Bunch (+15)';
        banana.src = 'images/banana6.png';
        countByTwo(3);
    }

    bananaCountText.textContent = bananaCount;
}

if (bananaCount > 10000 && !addFarm1) { // and this one to add one farm
    addFarm(1);
    addFarm1 = true;
}
```

Comment: Put them both in the `bananaClick()` function.

Comment: @Barmar yea ive tried that but js just executes whichever code comes first between the two so it doesnt execute both. cSharp gave an answer that worked and with only 4 extra lines

Comment: I've posted an answer showing how to do it. The only reason I can think of why yours didn't work is that you used `else if` for the second `if`. That should only be used for mutually-exclusive conditions.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
if (bananaCount > 10000) { // this one to change the clicker image, text, and interval
    bananaClicked.textContent = 'Golden Banana Bunch (+15)';
    banana.src = 'images/banana6.png';
    countByTwo(3);

    if(!addFarm1) {
        addFarm(1);
        addFarm1 = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: yea i ended up fixing it myself right after by doing something but this def is less characters. what i did was make a second if statement that was the exact same but if the addFarm1 var was true, then it would execute the normal code.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put both `if` statements in the function.

```
function bananaClick() {
  bananaCount += 1;

  if (bananaCount > 10000) { // this one to change the clicker image, text, and interval
    bananaClicked.textContent = 'Golden Banana Bunch (+15)';
    banana.src = 'images/banana6.png';
    countByTwo(3);
  }
  if (bananaCount > 10000 && !addFarm1) { // and this one to add one farm
    addFarm(1);
    addFarm1 = true;
  }
  bananaCountText.textContent = bananaCount;
}
```